# Finding the biggest number in Object Properties

Tags: javascript, max

I have a simple JS object literal, which gains a property.  I cannot figure out the math, or method of looking at the properties, selecting the highest value from the properties, and then displaying only that key.

```
var president = {"FDR":1,"Lincoln":2,"Buchanan":43,"Hoover":34};
    president.Obama = 3;
var x;
var txt = "";
for (x in president) {
  txt += president[x] + " ";
}
console.log(president);
```

I have seen several ways of trying to get max number, in this case 43 but returning "Buchanan", but none of them work within the console I am using.  `_.max` gives me "_ is not defined."    I tried a function call within the `Math.max.apply` method, and it gives me my initial list as the answer, but doesn't put the 5th president in that list.

If anyone can give me some old school hard coding to take in the object properties, including the new property I added, while using the `for in` loop, I would greatly appreciate it.  I can't find a good idea of how this is done.

Comment: Just check the number in every round of your loop. If it is bigger than the previous one, store the current one - including the name of the president -> done.

Comment: `_` is lodash (or underscore), a library. Do you have the library installed? If not, you won't be able to use it.  To select the highest value you need to start with a value, and every time you find one greater than that value, set the max value to the new max value--I don't see anything in the code that approaches that. To iterate an object's properties--this is easily searchable on the web.

Comment: `Math.max.call(null, Object.values(president))` (doesn't use the `for..in` loop, sorry).

Comment: Where did you get the code snippet that you posted and what makes you think that its actually an approach to solve your issue? That snippet is doing something completely different,

Comment: A valid approach would be to _sort_ the entries in your map by their values and afterwards access the last element in the resulting list.

Comment: @jota oh right, sorting an object ... great idea ...

Comment: @JonasWilms why not? sure, not the best approach but still a valid one. It could be a one-liner, e.g.: `Object.entries(obj).sort((a, b) => -1 * compareNumbers(a[1],b[1]))[0]`

Comment: @Jota.Toledo  Unfortunately, the way the professor has set up the console to test and work on the coding is not capable of using ```=>``` or other libraries that would use lodash.  Looking at your one-liner however, I am not fully understanding how it works.  This JS section of work is much more beginners, and uses very basic JS methods.  I get the ```Object.entries(president).sort((a, b)```, but then the rest of the snippet I do not get the logic of what it is doing.

Comment: @Abraxas thought so. You could turn the fat-arrow function into a normal anonymous function, AKA callback function. To understand the idea behind `compareNumbers` check [this MZ docs site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) . The idea is to sort the [key,value] pairs in descending order by their value (thats the reason for the `-1*`), and then access the first element of the resulting list, which will be a maximum.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo I checked the doc out.  Thank you, that helps me better understand that code snippet and what it is doing.  This section of the class is a learn on your own kind of deal.  There isn't an explicit portion of the class given to the intricacies of JS.  It would take longer than the class semester.  It is a HTML class, and the exercises the professor provided for us are a minor crash course, but JS is not a requirement of our final project.

Answer (score -2):

Try the following:

```js
var president = {"FDR":1,"Lincoln":2,"Buchanan":43,"Hoover":34};
    president.Obama = 3;

max = -1; //initial value;
pres = ""; //initial president

for (x in president) {
  if(president[x] > max){ //if the value is greater than max
     pres = x; //set the new president
     max = president[x]; //set the new max
  }
}
console.log(pres);
```

Comment: Hopefully you'll be there for the OP's exams, too. Wouldn't it be better to point them in the right direction rather than doing their homework?

Comment: I'm in class right now and cannot post a dissertation. If the OP was confused about any part of the code, he/she could comment and I would respond as fit. Did not know that posting an answer merited a snarky comment...

Comment: Posting an answer doesn't. Doing someone's work for them merits asking whether or not it's the best approach--interpreting that question as "snarky" is on you.

Comment: (Noting for the record that, IMO, up/down votes should indicate correctness/suitability rather than sharing an opinion on whether or not the answer is a "good idea", since reasonable people can disagree on that. But that's just me.)

Comment: @DaveNewton I wasn't explicitly asking to get a full fledged answer, but some clue to think how this would be done.  I can use this and learn from it.

Comment: @A.J.Uppal Ok, I see now how this logically runs through the object and checks each property, then store's it in ```max```.  In my previous code snippet, I was trying to figure out the math I would need to do, and wasn't recognizing how the code was looping, and then just giving me the full properties.  Now I realize more explicitly how the loop captures the data, stores it, then compares it to the next set of data.  Thank you.

Comment: @Abraxas There's no math other than a comparison (and certainly no string concatenation).

Comment: @DaveNewton ok the logic then.  I was thinking I was going to need to do some math, but I see now, with the answer above, better how the loop works.  I have just accepted that a loop works or it doesn't in the past, and barely understood the why it works.  A.J literally broke a wall in my logic process that I can understand now the way the loop works.  I will be much more cognizant of the process now.  Also, I didn't just come here to get an answer without any work on my part.  I have spent over 3 hours today, and 2 yesterday trying to figure the solution out.

Comment: @Abraxas If it was that confusing then it's best to break it down into "chunks": how do I iterate over an object's properties? (Pretty easy to search.) How do I access the property value I care about? (Here it's just the value attached to the property.) How do I figure out the maximum in a series of numbers? (Harder to search because most answers will use `Math.max`, which is for something different--but it's a common enough exercise; you really just need to capture the first value and use that as your current `max` then iterate over the rest of the properties.)

Comment: @DaveNewton what you said exactly, but I didn't know what to search.  "how do I iterate over an object's properties?"[sic]  Iterate. I didn't even consider that word in my searches.  In the end it is how you search that matters, and if you don't know the right keywords, you do get a bunch of things like: Maximize JS performance(from search) "Javascript, find maximum value of object properties."  I did get plenty of ```Math.max``` answers too, but none of them applied to my needs.  JS is not covered in the class explicitly, we have try to find the way ourselves.

Comment: But regardless of all that, I didn't come here without doing a lot of dead-end research, which didn't help me understand the idea of the exercise.  It never occurred to me that I would need to have a ```var max``` because I wasn't fully cognizant of the loop process.  But I will be now.

Comment: @DaveNewton my assumption was that the OP would be able to glean some understanding as to how the logic works based on the code and the comments. Evidently, from the above discussion, my assumption was correct. Not trying to have an argument on a Q&A site, but there is a nice way to say everything, and i'm not completely sure that includes asking me if i'm taking the OP's exams. Just a pointer.

Comment: You did their work for them instead of guiding. For me, that's a poor approach to helping someone. Evidently, from the voting, I'm not the only one with this opinion. Just a pointer. (And I didn't ask if you were taking their exams.) I find it difficult to believe you don't understand the difference between doing someone's work and guiding them to figuring it out--which means you're arguing for the sake of arguing, which while entertaining under some circumstances, is mostly just boring.

Comment: Not concerned about popular opinion. And in some cases, it is more helpful to show by example. If you doubt that, just see what the OP said: "A.J literally broke a wall in my logic process that I can understand now the way the loop works. I will be much more cognizant of the process now. Also, I didn't just come here to get an answer without any work on my part." And it takes two to parley, my friend, wouldn't be an argument otherwise.